# PHP use ENUM in Attributes

Tags: php, enums, php-8.1, php-attributes

Look at the following code:

```php
<?php

enum Types:string {
    case A = 'a';
    case B = 'b';
}

#[Attribute(Attribute::TARGET_CLASS)]
class MyAttribute {
    public function __construct(public readonly array $mapping)
    {
    }
}

#[MyAttribute(mapping: [Types::A->value => ''])]
class Entity {

}
```

It has error `Constant expression contains invalid operations`. I would like to use Enum value in my attribute for defining configuration. Seem like it is bug in php. Should it be reported or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when we call Types::A->value it actually creates instance of an enum, which is not a constant value.
To solve this problem define a constant and reference it.

```php
<?php

abstract class Type {
    public const A = 'a';
    public const B = 'b';
}

enum TypesEnum:string {
    case A = Type::A;
    case B = Type::B;
}

#[Attribute(Attribute::TARGET_CLASS)]
class MyAttribute {
    public function __construct(public readonly array $mapping)
    {
    }
}

#[MyAttribute(mapping: [Type::A => ''])]
class Entity {

}
```

Watch out for this [issue in php](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/9208)